# Fill NaN based on previous value of row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (sample, not real):

df =

```
    A   B   C    D   E     F       

0   3   4   NaN  NaN NaN   NaN  
1   9   8   NaN  NaN NaN   NaN      
2   5   9   4    7   NaN   NaN  
3   5   7   6    3   NaN   NaN  
4   2   6   4    3   NaN   NaN
```

Now I want to fill NaN values with previous couple(!!!) values of row (fill Nan with left existing couple of numbers and apply to the whole row) and apply this to the whole dataset.

- There are a lot of answers concerning filling the columns. But in
  this case I need to fill based on rows.
- There are also answers related to fill NaN based on other column, but
  in my case number of columns are more than 2000. This is sample data

Desired output is:

df =

```
   A  B   C  D  E  F  

0  3  4   3  4  3  4  
1  9  8   9  8  9  8  
2  5  9   4  7  4  7      
3  5  7   6  3  6  3  
4  2  6   4  3  4  3
```

Comment: What happens if an entire row is filled with `NaN`, or if only the first column is not `NaN`?

Comment: @DeepSpace idk. In my data set I have at least 1 couple of values. There is no full NaN row in the dataset

Comment: Are there ever `NaN` values at the beginning of a row?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IIUC, a quick solution without reshaping the data:

```
df.iloc[:,::2] = df.iloc[:,::2].ffill(1)
df.iloc[:,1::2] = df.iloc[:,1::2].ffill(1)
df
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  3  4  3  4  3  4
1  9  8  9  8  9  8
2  5  9  4  7  4  7
3  5  7  6  3  6  3
4  2  6  4  3  4  3
```

Answer (score 14):

Idea is reshape DataFrame for possible forward and back filling missing values with `stack` and modulo and integer division of `2` of array by length of columns:

```
c = df.columns 
a = np.arange(len(df.columns))
df.columns = [a // 2, a % 2]

#if possible some pairs missing remove .astype(int)
df1 = df.stack().ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1).unstack().astype(int)
df1.columns = c
print (df1)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  3  4  3  4  3  4
1  9  8  9  8  9  8
2  5  9  4  7  4  7
3  5  7  6  3  6  3
4  2  6  4  3  4  3
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.stack())
     0    1   2
0 0  3  NaN NaN
  1  4  NaN NaN
1 0  9  NaN NaN
  1  8  NaN NaN
2 0  5  4.0 NaN
  1  9  7.0 NaN
3 0  5  6.0 NaN
  1  7  3.0 NaN
4 0  2  4.0 NaN
  1  6  3.0 NaN
```